# Slack API : How to manage sessions in different channels?

Tags: session, slack, slack-api

I am developing a Slack Bot that gets data from a user and executes queries on it. But if there are 2 channels within the same workspace, and one channel provides the data, the other is then able to query on that data.

I want to prevent this behaviour by having different sessions for different channels. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Without more detail on how your app works, it's hard to make recommendations.

Do users query with slash commands? Shortcuts? Tagging your bot?

Answer (score 0):

As Colm mentioned in the comment, it would be helpful to know more about your application.

A generic answer to your question would be to scope your data by channel. For example, if your application receives slash commands, you will get all the necessary details [in the payload](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#app_command_handling). Therefore, when storing received data, use `team_id` and `channel_id` to scope the data to the relevant context.